# jquery function not called properly on form submit

Tags: jquery, html

When the email address is entered and the submit button is clicked, the `alert('jquery');` gets executed and I see the alert. **But I don't see alert for 'submitting the form'** and immediately the `request.php` page is served. What am I doing wrong?

**HTML snippet:**

```
<form class="form-signin" role="form" id="emailform" action="request.php" method="post"
  name="emailform">
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required="" /> <button name="submit"
    class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Get New Code</button>
</form>
```

**Jquery snippet:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert('jquery'); // this alert is called properly
        $("#emailform").submit(function(event) {

            alert('submitting the form'); // this is not getting called on click of the submit button
            event.preventDefault();

            var $form = $(this),
                url = $form.attr('action');
            alert(url);
            $.post(url, {
                    param1: $("#email").val()
                })
                .success(function(data) {
                    if (data == "found") {}
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Edit:** **The wording I used above is incorrect, and I am changing it hence, Thanks to @PeterKA**

" The `alert('jquery');` gets executed when the page is loaded, and I see the alert. But When the email address is entered and the submit button is clicked, the `alert('submitting the form');` is not getting executed"

Comment: Are you generating the HTML after page load?

Comment: @Kartikeya , Agree, but the button is of `type="submit"`. So the form submission happens when button is clicked, correct?

Comment: try `$(document.body).on('submit','#emailform',function(event){})`

Comment: @ROX , No The HTML is part of the page, and so I suppose the HTML is present when the document is loaded, am I wrong?

Comment: Is it true that ... *When the email address is entered and the submit button is clicked, the alert('jquery'); gets executed ..*?

Comment: Your code works correctly, [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xgkum0yn/2/).

Comment: two downvotes? :) surprised

Comment: YES. Because with your HTML and code there's no way your statement can be true: *When the email address is entered and the submit button is clicked, the alert('jquery'); gets executed ..* .. unless it is being caused by other code you've not shown.

Comment: I am checking why JSFiddle is working and mine is not.. Will update, Thanks @ROX

Comment: Apologies @PeterKA , I understood what you are telling. Will modify the text

Comment: @ROX Both the answers worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code; only you're misreporting what alert fires when. Please see the comments in the following demo. Run the demo to confirm that your code works as expected.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        
        //THIS ALERT FIRES WHEN THE PAGE LOADS
        //NOT WHEN A BUTTON IS CLICKED
        alert('jquery');
      
        $("#emailform").submit(function(event) {
            
            //THIS ALERT FIRES WHEN THE SUBMIT BUTTON IS CLICK
            //OR WHEN THE SUBMIT EVENT IS TRIGGERED THROUGH SOME OTHER MEANS
            alert('submitting the form');
          
            event.preventDefault();

            /*var $form = $(this),
                url = $form.attr('action');
            alert(url);
            $.post(url, {
                    param1: $("#email").val()
                })
                .success(function(data) {
                    if (data == "found") {}
                });*/
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-signin" role="form" id="emailform" action="request.php" method="post"
  name="emailform">
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required="" /> <button name="submit"
    class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Get New Code</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for that effort. That was my bad

Answer (score 0):

```
        <!DOCTYPE HTML>
        <html>
        <title>Tester</title>
        <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>





 <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
        alert('jquery'); // this alert is called properly
        $("#emailform").submit(function(event) {
            alert("hello this ready for submit");
           return false;
        });
    });

 </script>          


        </head>
        <body>

           <form class="form-signin" role="form" id="emailform" action="request.php" method="post"
  name="emailform">
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required="" /> <button name="submit"
    class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Get New Code</button>
</form>

        </body>
        </html>
```